# Support nested syntax highlighting, e.g. for GWT JSNI (JavaScript embedded in Java code)

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I have a feature request concerning syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow. I would like to be able to highlight code of nested syntax, e.g., for [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/)'s [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) functions, where JavaScript code is embedded in Java code.

Currently, such code renders like this:

[image: current highlighting]

I would prefer to have that code rendered like this (like Eclipse does with the GWT plugin):

[image: requested mixed highlighting]

Such cases of nested syntax occur in other places as well, e.g., for JavaScript embedded in Ant scripts (XML) etc., so this is not just a GWT-specific request.

The means of choosing the syntax of the nested part should probably be manual, e.g., by using some kind of markup. Detecting the syntax of the nested part automatically would be very hard.

SO syntax highlighting [is performed by Google Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/205238), which cannot handle nested syntax just like that; so some pre-processing may be required on the SO side. (Such as, maybe, splitting the code into three parts: upper Java; JavaScript; lower Java.)

---

**Update:** I fiddled a bit with Prettify and got it to produce nested highlighting without changing anything on the Prettify side: http://jsbin.com/lupuvonapu/2/edit?html,output
I tested the result with Firefox 17esr, IE10, Opera, and Safari, getting the desired result in all cases.

The approach used in the example supports only 1 level of nesting, and requires Prettify to run twice (once for the outer code, and again for nested code). I marked the nested code by adding a nested `<pre>` tag to specify its language syntax. This way of doing it certainly leaves room for improvement, but I hope it helps the idea along.

Comment: *Hopefully it is that easy.* Trust me, it isn't.

Comment: But it's a comment, so it _shouldn't_ be highlighted.

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's the point: It's *not* a comment. It's code.

Comment: @Thomas, *you* know it's code, but to a Java parser (especially to Prettify's parser), that's just a comment. The difficulty is 1) how to properly determine where embedded code begins and ends (assuming you don't want to run a parser for every language on every string and comment), and 2) how deep to go (e.g. should we prettify strings containing Javascript within VBScript fragments inside `<msxsl:script>` elements in an XSL stylesheet? Possibly embedded as CDATA inside another document?)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, those are (some of) the challenges. In my post, I suggest that some kind of markup be used to resolve this. I can't think of a way to detect such cases automatically.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Might want to post that as an answer?

Comment: related / relevant : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please/279361#279361 specially when it comes to *some pre-processing may be required on the SO side* which I expect would end up with a *No* from Oded...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight.js: For Real, Please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please)